# Runtime error 3464

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2013

I keep coming across 'run-time error 3464' with my script down below:

```
Private Sub ApproveTDS_Click()
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    Dim usr As String

    usr = DLookup("UserID", "tt_CurrentUser")
    DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE Table1 SET Table1.Date = Date(), Table1.ApprovedBy = '"& usr & "' WHERE Table1.Job = '" & Me!txtJobLU & "' And Table1.SN = '" & Me!txtJobSN & "'"
    Me.Refresh
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub

usr = varchar(255)
Table1.Date = Date
Table1.ApprovedBy = varchar(255)
Table1.Job = int
Table1.SN = varchar(50)
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you, Adam

Comment: Suggestions?  Sure:  Format your code as code so your question is readable.  (Put 4 spaces before each line.)  Google the error code; then, at least, if the results don't answer your question you can post a meaningful error instead of a code that I assure you 99% of us haven't memorized.

Comment: Sorry...I am new to this. Is this what you meant?

Comment: can you share table schema i suspect some datatype mismatch is there or DATE() is not returning correct format.

Comment: I edited your code, but I guess you still need to edit your question by adding other info...

Comment: Does this help at all??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WHERE Table1.Job = '" & Me!txtJobLU & "'`

If Job is an int, then wrapping it in quotes will not work - SQL Server thinks things in quotes are strings. Strings are not ints, therefore you get a data type mismatch. Remove the single quotes to fix this issue.

Better still though, in future learn to use parameterised queries - this code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.